# Feeding data to Xgboost for recomender system

Tags: xgboost, recommender-system

I am using xgboost for a recommender system. There are 3-4 recommended content on each page. My data consists of columns like page_id and advertisement_id. Currently for every page_id, there are 3-4 rows of advertisement_id in data. Xgboost then gives me the probability of likelihood of an ad being clicked.

It is known that one content(advertisement_id) from each page(page_id) is definitely clicked. I want to leverage this fact while training xgboost.

How can I tell xgboost that one ad_id from each page_id is definitely clicked?

Can this be done somehow by using a vector of advertisement_id for each row of page_id?

Comment: Pls clarify. What are your columns(predictors)? For each row (observation), you have a binary label for each ad (click/ not click)?

Comment: @horace: For each row I have, the category of web page viewed by user on which ad is shown, the advertiser information, ad topic, ad category information for each advertisement_id, Geo location of user and so on.

Comment: Yes there is a binary label of clicked/ not clicked.